# How can I trim an object by an exact mesure?

Tags: modeling, transforms

Is it possible to trim an object by 1mm from each side?

Scaling isn't really an option, because I don't exactly know the factor. I just want the model to be 1mm narrower from each side (each vertex should be "pushed" inside by 1mm).

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the size of the object with the x, y, and z size spinners the toolbar on the right of the 3d view.  All input fields can accept simple mathematical expressions so if the current size is .5m you can type “.5-.002” (.002 not .001 because you want 1mm off each side) and it will scale the object accordingly.

Comment: .002, because it's for both sides...

Comment: Thank you, but I'd rather avoid scaling and just trim the surface somehow.

Answer (score 3):

In edit mode, select all of the vertices on one side that you want to "trim", using your favorite method. Then, press the G-key, and the axis you are working with (X or Y), and enter .001 on the numeric keypad. As a more concrete example, if you have the object oriented so that the centerline is aligned with, or parallel to, the global Y axis, to narrow the object along the global X axis, you would press the key sequence

> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>

to move the selected vertices in the positive direction along the global X axis, and

> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>

to move the selected vertices in the negative direction along the global X axis.

If the centerline of your object is aligned with, or parallel to the global X axis, and you want to trim it along the global Y axis, then change the X in the above sequences to Y.

If it happens that the centerline of your object is not aligned with, or parallel to either the global X or global Y axis, you can move the selected vertices relative to the local X or local Y axes defined for the object itself by pressing the appropriate key twice. So, to move the selected vertices in a positive direction along the local X axis, the keypress sequence would be

> <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>

This technique does not affect any but the selected vertices, unless you have proportional editing enabled.

Comment: Your answer works if there's exactly 1 axis. However, I need something that would pull all vertices inside (where inside should be determined by the software, not me)